# Удвоение цикла при подписке на событие

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день!
Помогите разобраться.
Пишу Клиент - серверное приложение.
Начал подключать юзеринтерфейс с помощью wpf.

Есть кнопка Connect, которая в зависимость от состояния подключения к серверной части имеет функционал отключения/подключения. Делаю это с помощью событий, отслеживая в классе client свойство connect.

После первого нажатия происходит подключение, после второго отключение. А вот на третьем и далее происходит удвоение. Т.е. цикл проверки состояния connect бежит по нескольку раз. Есть подозрение на удвоение подписки на событие. Но удаление, перед новым добавлением ничего не дает.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        client.ConnectionTrue += ChangeConnectionButtonTrue;
        client.ConnectionFalse += ChangeConnectionButtonFalse;

    }

private void ChangeConnectionButtonTrue()
    {

        ConnectionButton.Content = "Disconnect";
        ConnectionButton.Click += ConnectionButton_Click_Disconnect;
    }
    private void ChangeConnectionButtonFalse()
    {
        ConnectionButton.Content = "Connect";
        ConnectionButton.Click += ConnectionButton_Click;
    }

    private void ConnectionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        client.Connect();
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Успешное подключение";
        }
        else AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Сервер не доступен";
    }

    private void ConnectionButton_Click_Disconnect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        client.Disconnect();
        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Отключен";
        }
        else AutorizatTextBlock.Text = "Сервер не доступен";
    }
}


class Client 
{
    const int port = 8888;
    const string address = "127.0.0.1";
    bool connected;
    public NetworkStream stream;
    TcpClient client;

    public  bool Connected
    {
        get { return connected; }
        set {
            if (connected != value)
            {
                connected = value;
                if (Connected)
                {
                    ConnectionTrue();
                }
                else
                {
                    ConnectionFalse();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Connect ()
        {
        try
        {
            if (!Connected)
            {
                client = new TcpClient(address, port);
                stream = client.GetStream();
                Connected = true;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Connected = false;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (Connected)
        {

                stream.Close();//отключение потока                  
                client.Close();//отключение клиента       
                Connected = false;
        }
    }
public delegate void ConnectionTrueHandler();
    public event ConnectionTrueHandler ConnectionTrue;

    public delegate void ConnectionFalseHandler();
    public event ConnectionFalseHandler ConnectionFalse;
```

}

Comment: Почему нельзя было хранить состояние `isConnected` и обычным `if` чекать при нажатии? У вас однозначно плохой солюшн. Я бы например сделал две кнопки, у каждой из которых своя задача (подключать одна, отключать другая). И работал бы с их видимостью, если необходимо прятать

Comment: Была идея с двумя кнопками, но смысл от них? Все равно, через отслеживание состояния Connected, необходимо скрывать / показывать кнопку. Ну и я не сильно силен еще в wpf, поэтому пока тяжело ориентироваться с подходами к проекту.

Comment: в первую очередь посмотрите в сторону `MVVM` патерна для разделения логики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void ChangeConnectionButtonTrue()
{
    ConnectionButton.Content = "Disconnect";
    ConnectionButton.Click -= ConnectionButton_Click;
    ConnectionButton.Click += ConnectionButton_Click_Disconnect;
}
private void ChangeConnectionButtonFalse()
{
    ConnectionButton.Content = "Connect";
    ConnectionButton.Click -= ConnectionButton_Click_Disconnect;
    ConnectionButton.Click += ConnectionButton_Click;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. В будущем учту, что при добавлении к кнопке события, они суммируются =)